# How to set the minimum approval status of a bundle and items in bundle in workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a bundle and bundle has 5 items in it. How can i set the approval status of all items to minimum approval status.  Currently i have set the approval status of Bundle in one of the workflow activity in visio. Do i need to do it explicitly in code some where?

Comment: You may disable the check for approval statuses for items that are not in Workflow

Comment: If i set the approval status of bundle in a activity to minimum approval status. Does it applies to all items in bundle or how can we set status of all items to minimum approval in activity. Do i need to do it explicitly or i am missing something here.

Comment: Each item that goes through workflow will get approval status which is set in the last activity definition. If bundle is in workflow - all of its items are also in workflow and hence will get same approval status as bundle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As items go past a given activity, they will all receive the approval status specified in that activity.

So, if you want all items to have "Draft" status after the workflow starts, for instance, you could create an automatic activity as your first activity, set the approval status of that activity to "Draft" and in code just finish the activity automatically (and possibly publish to staging).

This status will apply to ALL items in the same bundle.